# Remove password authentication for ssh sessions based on client address

Tags: ssh

I manage two networks for my research group that both exist on my department's network. The first (`casual_net`) can be connected to from any address via password and public-key authentication. The second network (`fast_net`) is a high performance cluster that should be a protected a bit more. It only accepts connections from *.myschool.edu and *.physics.myschool.edu. Its users almost always log in first to `casual_net`, then into `fast_net` via password authentication.

I would like to extend connections to `fast_net` to include public-key authentications w/o a host limitation, but can't figure out how to implement it while maintaining the restrictions for password logins. Anyone lend a hand?

I was checking [this webpage](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch07_01.htm#ch07-34735) and from O'Reilly's SSH guide I see syntax I might use for limiting access by editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Here's my attempt:

```
Host *.myschool.edu
 PasswordAuthentication yes

Host *
 PasswordAuthentication no
```

I apologize for not trying this before asking SO; if I botch the ssh service and can't log in remotely then I've screwed myself for the night for the rest of the work I'm doing on there.